# Paper Trail for .Net

Tags: .net, database

I've been diving into ruby lately and have found the gem [Papertrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) to be an amazing auditing and undo tool.

Question is, does something like this exist for the .Net flavor of development? A project at work has need of change management and I have been unable to locate anything like this through google fu, but surely someone has solved this with a similar

Comment: something like: http://help.papertrailapp.com/

Comment: @peer: You can find information on gems [here](http://gembundler.com/). lazyPower is probably looking for [something like this.](https://nuget.org/packages?q=audit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And years later, I come back to this. I'm no longer writing in .Net but an equivalent [tool exists for RavenDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.Bundles.Versioning/)

RavenDB Versioning Bundle
By:

```
ayende
```

The versioning bundle will create snapshots for every document upon every update made to it, or when it is deleted. It is useful when you need to track history of documents, or when you need a full audit trail.

Which does exactly what I was looking for.